# Opening Esri .gdb database with values coded or stored in domains

Tags: qgis, gdal, file-geodatabase, domains

I have a `.gdb` file with multiple layers of different geometries and a table called "Toolbox". When i import it into QGIS it shows me all the layers and the "Toolbox" as a table. Some of the fields in some layers have only integer codes as values. Apparently these are codes for a "domain solution" that link to a domain or something in which values are stored as text. I got sent a screenshot that shows me the text values.

Is there a way to open a `.gdb` file to read coded domain values?

I am using QGIS version 3.34.2-Prizren.

So that for example `Rechtlicher Status` is shown as 'Grundsatz' instead of '9999'.

This is how i looks in QGIS:
[image]

The toolbox layers attribute table, not sure if this is of any importance.
[image]

This is how it should look like:
[image]

Comment: Witch version of QGIS do you use ? In recent QGIS version (since 3.28 : https://north-road.com/2022/11/24/qgis-3-28-improvements-for-working-with-esri-formats-and-services/) domain from file .gdb are read and should be used automatically in the form as value map

Comment: @m4D_guy Please update your question to provide the QGIS Version you are using.

Comment: Use the QGIS browser to navigate to your .gdb and look if the domain are included in it (if yes you should see a "field domain" table)

Comment: The toolbox "layer" is an esri toolbox that have been saved in the gdb. This has nothing to do with domain and as far as I know can't be used within QGIS